# FixtureSetup on MbUnit / Gallio doesn't run

Tags: mbunit, gallio

I don't understand this problem. First I had MBUnit v2 referenced and everything worked perfectly. Then I installed and referenced MBunit v3... Which seems to be MbUnit.dll and Gallio.dll in the Gallio install bin-folder. And when I compiled I got some warnings on TestFixtureSetup, so I changed those to FixtureSetup. But now they don't get executed anymore. Any clues what I'm doing wrong?

Which dll's should I reference btw? Because when I used v2 of MbUnit I always used MbUnit.Framework.dll but that doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

I'am confused...

**Edit:**
This example explains my problem best I think:

I tried this using TestDriven.NET:

```
[TestFixture]
    public class CategoryTests 
    {
        [FixtureSetUp]
        public void _TestFixtureSetup()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("in fixturesetup");
        }

        [Test]
        public void test()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("in test");
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
}
```

Upon rightclicking on the test method and choosing Run Test(s) I get this output:

```
------ Test started: Assembly: mvcstore.DataAccess.Tests.dll ------

in test

1 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, took 1.13 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only the 2 following assemblies: MbUnit.dll and Gallio.dll. Be sure to use the new runner because the old one (mbunit v2) is not compatible with mbUnit v3.

Icarus is the GUI runner and Echo is the command line runner.

Comment: I'm using Testdriven.NET... Is that a problem

Comment: Do you see "Ad-Hoc" in the TestDriven.Net output?  If so, then the Gallio TestDriven.Net components have not been installed correctly.  You will need to run the Gallio installer again and ensure that the Runners -> TestDriven.Net components are being installed.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the input, I will try it. However on googling the error I think my problem is related to this persons: http://groups.google.com/group/gallio-dev/browse_thread/thread/68d09ac78b14dba3 because I'm also using 64bit operatig system(Windows XP).

Comment: Jeff, I don't see "Ad-Hoc" in the output. So I guess the problem is something else. I edited my question a bit.

Comment: You are correct that only MbUnit.dll and Gallio.dll need to be referenced.

I'm confused by the sample output because Gallio wouldn't even print "in test" directly.  Instead it would capture the output and include it in the linked report.  If it were working then you would see "Gallio" in the output and a link to the report at the end.

Consequently I don't think Gallio is actually installed correctly.  Make sure you download and install the 64bit MSI for Gallio v3.0.6 Update 2.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that I had installed the x86 version of Gallio instead of the 64bit version. Now everything is working